# Iterate Objects in MongoDB using Aggregation Pipeline

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following content in my [MongoDB](http://pasted.co/3445058a). It's a lot of information but I only need part of the content. I would like to use MongoDB aggregation framework to iterate over the different objects.

I have tried this code:

```
db.data.aggregate([
       { $group : {
            _id : "$Ottawa.location.name",         
            Current : {
                $push : {
                    Temperature : "$Ottawa.current.temperature",
                    Humidity : "$Ottawa.current.humidity",
                    Date : "$Ottawa.current.date",
                    Feelslike : "$Ottawa.current.feelslike",
                    Windspeed : "$Ottawa.current.windspeed"
                }
            },
            Forecast : {$push :{
                Low : "$Ottawa.forecast.low",
                High : "$Ottawa.forecast.high",
                Date : "$Ottawa.forecast.date"
            }}
        }
    },
])
```

Currently I can only aggregate the data for one city. I would like to iterate the cities.

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: Currently I can only aggregate the data for one city. I would like to iterate the cities.

Comment: Can you add your code where you are calling `aggregate()` to your question?

Comment: I tried [this](https://jsfiddle.net/qL6yapby/) code

Comment: Your comments would make this question a lot clearer as part of your question (it helps it show up on searches)

Comment: Thanks for the edit.